# Why does my perl hash deform my array data?

Tags: perl

I have encountered some interesting behavior in Perl, and was hoping to be enlightened.
As you can see I create an array called `@tuple` that has two array references.  When I assign it to a key and extract it I only get the first array VALUE as apposed to the reference.  Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
my @VMstoreName = ($storeName[$i]);
my @VMdiskCap   = ($diskCap[$i]);
print "VMstoreName : ". join(' ', @VMstoreName) . "\n";
print "VMdiskCap : ". join(' ', @VMdiskCap) . "\n";
# Initializing our key
my @tuple =  (\@VMstoreName, \@VMdiskCap);
print "After tuple " . join(' ', @tuple) . "\n";

@virtualMachines{$vmNames[$i]} = @tuple;
my @DEBUG = @{$virtualMachines{$vmNames[$i]}};
print "After first map : " . join(' ', @DEBUG) . "\n";
print "WHAT??? $DEBUG[0] $DEBUG[1]!!!\n";
```

Here is the output, I want After first map to read exactly like After tuple

```
VMstoreName : 172.16.1.3:/export/Paul/test-0
VMdiskCap : 1   
After tuple ARRAY(0x2c4ccf0) ARRAY(0x2c4cd38)
After first map 172.16.1.3:/export/Paul/test-0
WHAT??? 172.16.1.3:/export/Paul/test-0 !!!
```

Comment: What did you expect? Please provide expected output. Also, your actual output and your code don't match: the code say `After hash`, but the output `After first map`?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the print error, but I stated above that I want the line After first map to read exactly like after tuple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning to your Hash in list context using the same key. Keys have to be unique in hashes, so only one reference gets stored inside of your Hash. The Hash-slice is only 1-element wide so the second reference just gets ignored.

You should assign a *reference* to `@tuple` instead using scalar context:

```
$virtualMachines{$vmNames[$i]} = \@tuple;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.  I did not know that perl would chop off the value like that!

Comment: @dakillakan Compare with `my @x = (3, 4); my ($y) = @x;` (and indeed with `my ($z) = (3, 4);`).  Perl would love to assign the remaining values, but you do need to give it a place to put them.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem begins here (I guess):

```
 @virtualMachines{$vmNames[$i]} = @tuple;
```

`@hash{...}` is a hash slice: It accesses mutiple entries in the hash at once (this may be only one entry). A slice as LHS value imposes list context.

To this list we assign the values of `@tuple`.

Now list assignment has the property of forgetting superfluous values:

```
my ($x, $y) = (1, 2, 3); # nobody likes № 3
```

So the above statement is the same as

```
$virtualMachines{ $vmNames[$i] } = $tuple[0];
```

Specifically, this assigns an array reference to the `%virtualMachines` entry, as `@tuple` only holds arrayrefs.

On the next line, you access this entry via `$virtualMachines{$vmNames[$i]}`. This evaluates to an array reference. You then *dereference* this to an array with `@{ ... }`.

This assigns all the values of that array to `@DEBUG`, not the array reference. As seen in your debug statement, this is the VMstoreName.

#### Solution

Assign an arrayref to the `%virtualMachines` entry:

```
$virtualMachines{ $vmNames[$i] } = \@tuple;
```

Arrays and hashes can *only* hold scalars, so we can't use an array as value, only an *array reference*.

Answer (score -2):

You are passing *references to arrays* when you initialize `@tuple`. Instead, just pass the arrays:

```
my @tuple = (@VMstoreName, @VMdiskCap);
```

Answer (score -2):

It looks like `@tuple` is an array of array references. You'll have to deference each element to print them out the way you intend to.

```
my @tuple =  (\@VMstoreName, \@VMdiskCap);
print "After tuple " . join(' ', map { @$_ } @tuple) . "\n";
```